# Renaming JPG files in R

Tags: r, rename

I have a field map where I took images of the plots. The pictures were taken from left to right and serpentined like that; so, from 101, 118, 119, 136,137,138,135,120,117,102,103,116...etc. The pictures are in this order as well; however, they are in a differnt name that doesnt correspond to the plot and it the file names look like this 100_498, 100_499, 100_500, 100_501. So for further detail plot 101 is equal to file 100_498 and plot 118 is equal to file 100_499 etc...I need to be able to rename the files going by how they took the pictures in the field to what they correspond too by the plot map below. If I were to rename them with my code it would go from top to bottom and since it serpentines, the pictures would be in order in the folder.

Now I need to re-do the R code...any suggestions??? 
I need to rename these files so that it corresponds to this plot.

Here is my code if it would they would have taken the data from bottom to top and serpentined... 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112...etc.

```
Plot map
109 110 127 128 145
108 111 126 129 144
107 112 125 130 143
106 113 124 131 142
105 114 123 132 141
104 115 122 133 140
103 116 121 134 139
102 117 120 135 138
101 118 119 136 137

f <-list.files(pattern="*.JPG") #imports files names
head(f) #first 6 rows of data

new_names <- paste("Plot_", #create new file name
               formatC(seq(length(file_names)), #writes the number in 
                #sequential order
               width=2,flag="0"), 
               ".JPG",sep="")
head(new_names) #first 6 rows of data
file.rename(from=f, to=new_names) #replaces old file name with new file name
list.files(pattern=".JPG") #check to make sure it was done
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function converts a `fileno` into the `100_498` format you are looking for.  This example works for your particular case, but you might like to parametrise it if you need to use it more generally.

```
filecoords <- function(fileno){
  fcol <- 498 + (fileno - 101) %/% 9
  frow <- ifelse(fcol %% 2, 108-((fileno-101) %% 9),100+((fileno-101) %% 9))
  return(paste(frow, fcol, sep="_"))
}

filecoords(c(101, 105, 124))

[1] "100_498" "104_498" "105_500"
```

The inverse function might also be useful.  It takes a string such as "104_498" and returns a filename "Plot_nnn" using the numbers as in your plot map.

```
filenos <- function(coord){
  coords <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(coord,"_")))
  base <- 9*(coords[2]-498)+101
  fileno <- base+ifelse(coords[2] %% 2,8-((coords[1]-100) %% 9),(coords[1]-100) %% 9)
  return(paste0("Plot_",fileno))
}

filenos("105_500")
[1] "Plot_124"
```

So you can then use something like this to rename your files...

```
oldfiles <- list.files(pattern="\\.JPG") #get list of files
oldfilestems <- gsub("\\.JPG","",oldfiles) #remove the suffix
newfilestems <- sapply(oldfilestems,filenos) #assumes your old file stems are "100_498" format
newfiles <- paste0(newfilestems,".JPG") #add the suffix
file.rename(oldfiles,newfiles) #rename
```

Comment: I think this is what i wanted by renaming the files in the correct order. I just need the files to be converted from current file name 100_3753 to file name Plot_101 for all the files.

Comment: I've added an inverse function - does that help?

Comment: Yes, this does help a lot. I had one problem with the coding though however...so plots 101, 118, 119, 136, 137 should be equal to the current file names 100_498, 100_499, 100_500, 100_501, and 100_502 respectively. I think plots 101, 119, and 137 were correct but plots 118, and 136 were both negative 6 plots off.

Comment: Also...this didn't change the actual file name in my folder...f<-list.files(pattern="*.JPG") I tried using the file.rename(from=filenos, to=f) but i displayed an error that the from was argument was not the right length. For the last question i didn't understand how you adjust the numbers to be shifted up 6 for the even colums.

Comment: Sorry about the mistake in the formula. I've now corrected it in the above, and added something about how to actually rename your files.

Comment: One more problem with the code...It did plot 101, 118, 119, 136, 137 like it did; however, it kept going to 157, 155, 172, 173...etc. but the plot map serpentines so after plot 137 it should serpentine back to plot 138, 135, 120, 117, 102 and serpentine back around to 103, 116, 121...etc all the way up the to the top row and those plots would respectively correspond to 100_503, 100_ 504, 100_505, 100_506, 100_507, 100_508, 100_509, 100_510.

Comment: Sorry - I think I have misunderstood how your system works.  I thought the `100` part of `100_nnn` was an index that changed to `101, 102` etc - which seems not to be the case.  I have posted a new answer - hopefully this will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The following function creates a lookup table to convert a zig-zag in one direction to a zig-zag in the other direction...

```
zigzag <- function(n=45,r=9){ #n=number of plots, r=number of rows
  #create desired new order as a matrix
  new <- matrix(1:n,nrow=r)
  even <- 2*seq_len(ncol(new)/2)
  new[,even] <- apply(new[,even],2,rev)

  #create old order as a matrix
  old <- t(matrix(1:n,ncol=r))
  even <- 2*seq_len(nrow(old)/2)
  old[even,] <- t(apply(old[even,],1,rev))

  #reduce to vectors and return look-up table as a dataframe
  df <- data.frame(old=as.vector(old),new=as.vector(new))
  return(df)
}
```

You can then rename your files as follows...

```
lookup <- zigzag() #create lookup table

oldfiles <- paste0("100_",497+lookup$old,".JPG") 
newfiles <- paste0("Plot_",100+lookup$new,".JPG")

file.rename(oldfiles,newfiles)

head(oldfiles,10)
 [1] "100_498.JPG" "100_507.JPG" "100_508.JPG" "100_517.JPG" "100_518.JPG" "100_527.JPG" "100_528.JPG" "100_537.JPG"
 [9] "100_538.JPG" "100_499.JPG"
head(newfiles,10)
 [1] "Plot_101.JPG" "Plot_102.JPG" "Plot_103.JPG" "Plot_104.JPG" "Plot_105.JPG" "Plot_106.JPG" "Plot_107.JPG"
 [8] "Plot_108.JPG" "Plot_109.JPG" "Plot_118.JPG"
```

Comment: Great this works...One thing I noted though, i had to slightly jimmy rig my system...I had to use my old code from my question to rename the files in sequential order first with no gaps because I deleted some pictures in the folder. The new code replaced the names in sequential order of the first file (number) so I would end up with the last file as Plot_49 when there were only 45 plots because I deleted four pictures. After I renamed the files first in order, the new code worked great for the pattern I requested the code for and renamed the files perfectly.